Appending multiple dictionaries to specific key of a nested dictionary
I want to append different dictionaries having the key as the meal_name and having total_calories and total_protein as a tuple being the value of the dictionary without overwriting the original dictionaries under the main dictionary having date as the key value.
I tried using the code below to add the new dictionary but it overwrites the previous one.
date = input("Enter the date in (Day-Month-Year) format: ")
name = input("Enter the name of the meal: ")
current_meal[name] = (total_calories, total_protein)
meal_data[date] = current_meal

This is what the dictionary looks like:
{'23-07-2024': {'Smoothie': (245.0, 17.0)}}

Suppose I want to add a new meal to the existing date without overwriting the Smoothie dictionary. Is this possible.

So you want to add a new key-value pair to the inner dictionary, eg. {'Smootie':(..., ...), 'Juice':(..., ...)}?

You should associate a list (the value) with the date key. You can then append your "meals" to that list

You can use the if-else statement to check whether the current date is in the dictionary.
date = input("Enter the date in (Day-Month-Year) format: ")
name = input("Enter the name of the meal: ")
if date in meal_data: # If date is already in meal_date then set the current_meal to existing meal
    current_meal = meal_data[date]
else: # if not then set it to empty dict
    current_meal = {}

current_meal[name] = (total_calories, total_protein) # Adding new meal to the current_meal
meal_data[date] = current_meal

OUTPUT


I would suggest making use of the nested key in the dictionary, like this:
meal_dict = {}

meal_dict['23-07-2024'] =  {'Smoothie': (245.0, 17.0)}
meal_dict['23-07-2024']['Salad'] = (400.0, 10.0)

Which outputs:
{'23-07-2024': {'Smoothie': (245.0, 17.0), 'Salad': (400.0, 10.0)}}


Try using .update() method, By this if the key(date in your case) exists the new meal will be added without overwriting the existing meal!

Hi karen. Welcome to Stackoverflow.
Unfortunatelly, your answer is not correct at this time. The update method of dicionaries would overwrite values on the same date as any keys passed as arguments on the update call - so, it would not solve the OP problem.

Since you are in a mood to contribute, I suggest you research (and try by yourself before comming up with a final text) the .setdefault method of dictionaries, in combination with a default list ([])  - that would uphold the OP expectatives. This answer as is (suggesting .update) is subject to being downvoted.
